# ASUS Zenbook UX433/UX333 --- Configure Touchpad-embedded numpad on Linux

Tags: linux, drivers, touchpad, asus, zenbook

I have an ASUS Zenbook UX433,on which ASUS decided to innovate by embedding a Numpad inside the touchpad (see picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ToKR.jpg)).

Toggling between classic touchpad mode and numpad (also turns the touchpad LEDs on) can be done through the golden button in the top-right corner of the touchpad.

However, on my Manjaro arch Linux config, this behavior does not work by default and I can only use the touchpad, no numpad.

**Has anyone been able to configure the numpad to work on Linux, or have any idea how this could be achieved?**

[image: ASUS Zenbook Tactile Numpad]

EDIT1: I have had a look at the [official Windows drivers for the UX433FA TouchPad](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/DriversForWin10/TouchPad/Touchpad_ASUS_Win10_64_VER120014.zip), but was not able to make anything of it. I tried installing them on Linux using tools like NDISWrapper, but they do not detect the TouchPad/Numpad hardware, and my understanding of drivers is too limited.

Comment: No there is no way to make it works at the moment :/ Good laptop though

Comment: Any updates on getting this to work? It is indeed a great laptop!

Comment: Well, I don't have any new information at the moment. There is only [one other thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1810183) about it. It looks like we will have to wait for an official driver release.

Comment: You can try this one
https://github.com/mohamed-badaoui/ux433-touchpad-numpad